# chown(): Operation not permitted occurred due to chown-soket of uwsgi【nginx】

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I tried to run a django program using nginx and uwsgi, but the following error occurs in nginx.

```
connect() to unix:/var/www/html/view/dbproject/dbproject.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream
```

I thought this error was probably because the owner of dbproject.sock, which is created when uwsgi is started, is `username:username` and not `username:www-data`.

Therefore, I added `chown-soket = %(username):www-data` in the uwsgi initialization file uwsgi.ini, but when I restart uwsgi, `chown(): Operation not permitted` is written in the uwsgi log.

How can I make the socket owner `%(username):www-data`?

Thank you.

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
# path to your project
chdir           =  /var/www/html/view/dbproject
username        =  myusername
# path to wsgi.py in project
module          =  dbproject.wsgi:application
master          =  true
pidfile         =  /var/www/html/view/dbproject/django.uwsgi.pid
socket          =  /var/www/html/view/dbproject/dbproject.sock
# http            =  127.0.0.1:8000
# path to python virtualvenv
home            =  /var/www/html/view/myvenv
chown-socket    =  %(username):www-data
chmod-socket    =  660
enable-threads  =  true
processes       =  5
thunder-lock     = true
max-requests    =  5000
# clear environment on exit
vacuum          =  true
daemonize       =  /var/www/html/view/dbproject/django.uwsgi.log
# Django settings
env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = dbproject.settings
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved.

I used root permission to start uwsgi.

I was using the Python virtual environment. However, the user when entering the virtual environment was not `root`. So all Python commands used in this situation are `uid=username, gid=username`. In other words, the following `uwsgi` command and the `chown` command executed by `uwsgi` will also be executed by `username`.

```
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
```

However, as far as I know, the `chown` command causes a permission error if used by anyone other than root. Therefore, I think that the `chown-socket` in the uwsgi initialization file, which was executed by `username`, was causing permission errors.

So my operation is as follows

```
sudo -s # root permission
source myvenv/bin/acitvate # load python venv by root
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini # excute uwsgi by root
```

I am concerned that uwsgi will not work without root because of the problem if it is a public system, but if you have a better solution than mine, please point it out.